# How can I abort deletion of record based on decisions after dbnavigator delete button pressed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ttnavigator, anydac

Can I abort deletion of record based on decisions after `dbnavigator` delete button pressed?
I checked `beforeAction` Event

```
if Button = nbDelete then  
  //check if not OK then

Button := nbCancel;
```

but it doesn't work. Any Help?

I'm using `DelPhi XE2, anyDac Components`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **BeforeAction** event

```
procedure TForm1.DBNavigator1BeforeAction(Sender: TObject; Button: TNavigateBtn);
begin
  if Button = nbDelete then
  begin
    if MessageDlg('Confirm delete now?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes,mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    begin
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BeforeDelete event:

```
procedure Tdm.MyDataSetBeforeDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if SomeCondition then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Sorry, you can not delete this record.');
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the DBNavigator, then on the Object Inspector inside the Options set the noConfirmDelete to "false"